# iOS UITableView Separator distorted on orientation change to back to portrait

Tags: ios

I am using `custom tableview cell`.

When I change my device orientation from `Portrait to Landscape then Cell autoresize` it's subviews, but when I again change orientation back to portrait the cell separator clipped.

**This is happening only in iOS 7**. in iOS 6 and 5  I am not able to recreate this issue.

`Is this iOS 7 issue` or `I it can be my silly mistake on coding side`.

Please let me know if there is any clue about this problem.

Comment: Can you add screen shots for the problem?

Comment: Did you customize the cell separator ?

Comment: I tried to add the screen shot but my account is restricted to add image.